# Logging will not display calling Methods or Line Numbers

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

I've set up logging for a project I've developed, but I cannot seem to get line numbers and calling methods to show up in the logs.  I have a Maven project, and the `maven-compiler-plugin` is configured to include debug information in the compiled classes.

It'd be very helpful for me to have this information in the logs, and for me to understand why that's not happening right now.  Can someone help to explain to me what's going on here and how I can get method names and line numbers in my logs?

Here's my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>3.0.1</cxf.version>
        <log4j.version>2.0.2</log4j.version>
        <wsdl.dir>generated\wsdl</wsdl.dir>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Nuance-to-Edify Web Services</name>
    <description>This project will handle communication between servers.</description>

    <build>
        <finalName>n2e-ws</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <!-- CREATE WAR -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>

                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- INCLUDE SOURCE FILES WITH WAR -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>

                        <!-- INCLUDE RESOURCES WITH WAR -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}\..\resources</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>

                        <!-- INCLUDE WSDLS WITH WAR -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}\${wsdl.dir}</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/wsdl</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- GENERATE WSDL FOR EACH SERVICE -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-account-service-wsdl</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.company.ws.data.services.interfaces.AccountServiceEndpointInterface</className>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}\${wsdl.dir}\AccountService.wsdl</outputFile>
                            <address>REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL</address>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-logging-service-wsdl</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.company.ws.data.services.interfaces.LoggingServiceEndpointInterface</className>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}\${wsdl.dir}\LoggingService.wsdl</outputFile>
                            <address>REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL</address>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-search-service-wsdl</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.company.ws.data.services.interfaces.SearchServiceEndpointInterface</className>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}\${wsdl.dir}\SearchService.wsdl</outputFile>
                            <address>REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL</address>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-validation-service-wsdl</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.company.ws.data.services.interfaces.ValidationServiceEndpointInterface</className>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}\${wsdl.dir}\ValidationService.wsdl</outputFile>
                            <address>REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL</address>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- mvn clean install tomcat:run-war to deploy Look for "Running war 
                        on http://xxx" and "Setting the server's publish address to be /yyy" in console 
                        output; WSDL browser address will be concatenation of the two: http://xxx/yyy?wsdl -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-tomcat</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run-war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <port>${test.server.port}</port>
                                <path>/*</path>
                                <fork>true</fork>
                                <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                        <debuglevel>lines,source,vars</debuglevel>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>3.5</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.cxf
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            cxf-java2ws-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${cxf.version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.3.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- COMPILE DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <classifier>with-deps</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PROVIDED/TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here's my log4j2.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration
    status="debug"
    monitorInterval="600">

    <Appenders>
        <Console
            name="CONSOLE"
            target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d [%4.4t] [%5.5p] %35.35c(%15.15M):%-5.5L - %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File
            name="EDIFY-NUANCE"
            fileName="../logs/n2e-ws.log">
            <!--<PatternLayout
                pattern="%d [%4.4t] [%5.5p] %35.35c(%15.15M):%-5.5L - %m%n" />-->
             <PatternLayout pattern="%d %5p %20.30c [%t] %20.30C (%F:%L) %m%n" 
                /> 
        </File>
        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="EDIFY-NUANCE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <logger
            name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header"
            level="fatal"
            additivity="false" />
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `includeLocation="true"` in the configuration for async loggers or for async appenders. See also http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Location and http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#AsyncAppender

By the way, your configuration has a logger (with name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header") that does not have an AppenderRef. That won't work.

So, put those together and your config should look like this:

```
<Appenders>
    ...
    <Async name="ASYNC" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="EDIFY-NUANCE" />
        <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
    </Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header"
            level="fatal" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: You got me on the right track, although I did have to modify your advice to get my issue resolved.  And I want to specifically thank you for including references and articles relevant to the subject.  That said, the attribute `includeLocation="true"` must be added to the ASYNC appender: `<Async name="ASYNC" includeLocation="true">...`  If you modify your answer to reflect this, I'll mark it as Accepted.